# Multidimensional center-of-mass coordinates for PDE solutions

Tags: pde

In this question I'm looking for a discussion on coordinate transformations. Say I have a PDEs of the form
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \, V(t,x) \ = \ \Bigg\{r(x,t) - \sum_{m=1}^D \mu_m(t,x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_m} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{m=1}^D\sum_{n=1}^D\Gamma_{mn}(t,x) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_m \partial x_n}\,\Bigg\} \; V(t,x) \,,
$$
and I want to transform the coordinates $\{x_i\}_{i=1 \ldots D}$ to what I'd call generalized center-of-mass coordinates. That is, in the new coordinates $\{y_j\}$, the first dimension should be $y_1 = \frac{1}{D}\sum_i x_i$.

As far as I remember, there is a Jacobi matrix $J$ which connects the two coordinate systems,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_D\end{pmatrix} = J \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_D\end{pmatrix} 
$$
For center-of-mass coordinates, the first row of $J$ should consist of constants, $J_{1i} = \frac{1}{D}(1,\ldots,1)$. With this, there are $D-1$ rows left to choose, with the constraint that $J$ should have full rank and usually also be orthogonal. Moreover, I would choose the Jacobian as a matrix with constant entries (unlike in spherical coordinates, say, where the Jacobian depends on the position).

Questions:

1. What are standard approaches for generalized center-of-mass coordinates?
2. Do these approaches fit in the simple framework above? If yes, what is the strategy for assembling the other coordinates $y_2, \ldots, y_D$ beside the center of mass $y_1$?
3. Is there a systematic way to find a Jacobi matrix such that the PDE above remains "as easy as possible"?
4. As a quick idea, one could simply choose the rows $2$ to $D$ with random constants, and then apply Gram-Schmidt to obtain an orthogonal matrix -- any comments on that?

Please feel free to answer only parts of these questions and maybe also to provide an alternative view.